# SQL query help: error in Inserting into temp table from stored procedure

Tags: sql

I have a stored procedure which output a column. It runs without problem.

```
exec dbo.sp_SelectAlignmentSubset
     @AlnID
    ,@ParentTaxID
    ,@SeqTypeID
    ,@LocationID
    ,@SubsetSize
    ,@SimilarityThreshold
    ,@SimilarityTable
    ,@AnchorSeqID
```

But when I insert the procedure output into a temp table,

```
create table #resultSeqIDs
(
    SeqID int not null
)

Insert into #resultSeqIDs
exec dbo.sp_SelectAlignmentSubset
     @AlnID
    ,@ParentTaxID
    ,@SeqTypeID
    ,@LocationID
    ,@SubsetSize
    ,@SimilarityThreshold
    ,@SimilarityTable
    ,@AnchorSeqID
```

error pop out `"The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file. Roll back the transaction."`

Thanks in advance.

The query of the procedure is here:

```
Alter Proc dbo.sp_SelectAlignmentSubset
    @AlnID int,
    @ParentTaxID int,
    @SeqTypeID int,
    @LocationID int,
    @SubsetSize int,
    @SimilarityThreshold float,
    @SimilarityTable nvarchar(255),
    @AnchorSeqID int = null
As
    declare @sql nvarchar(4000), @param nvarchar(2000), @subsetActualSize int, @lastSeqID int, @meanSimilarity float

    --- Cleaning
    begin try 
        drop table #Subset
    end try
    begin catch
    end catch
    begin try 
        drop table #tmpAllSeqs
    end try
    begin catch
    end catch
    begin try 
        drop table #AllSeqs
    end try
    begin catch
    end catch

    --- Create temp tables
    create table #Subset
    (
        SeqID int not null
    )

    create table #AllSeqs
    (
        SeqID int not null
    )

    create table #tmpAllSeqs
    (
        SeqID int not null,
        Similarity float not null
    )

    --- Prepare anchor 
    if @AnchorSeqID is not null
    begin
        Insert into #Subset values (@AnchorSeqID)
        set @lastSeqID = @AnchorSeqID
    end

    --- Get all SeqIDs in the alignment under the parent taxID
    Insert into #AllSeqs
    Select  SeqID
    from    dbo.fn_SelectAlignedSequences(@AlnID, @ParentTaxID, @SeqTypeID, @LocationID)


    --- Put SeqIDs into #Subset
    select @subsetActualSize = count(*) from #Subset

    while  @subsetActualSize < @SubsetSize
    begin
--      select 'Subset size:'+cast(@subsetActualSize as nvarchar(10))
        truncate table #tmpAllSeqs

        set @sql = 
        '   Insert  into #tmpAllSeqs
            select   st.SeqID2 as SeqID
                    ,st.Similarity
            from ' + @SimilarityTable + ' st
            where   st.SeqID1 = @lastSeqID
            and     st.SeqID2 in ( select SeqID from #AllSeqs )
            and     st.Similarity <= @SimilarityThreshold
        '
        set @param = '@lastSeqID int, @SimilarityThreshold float'
        exec sp_executesql @sql, @param, @lastSeqID, @SimilarityThreshold

        --- Mark the SeqID will be selected from #AllSeqs and
        --- added to #Subset in this round
        ---
        --- Here I select the SeqID with minimum difference from 
        --- mean of similarity as the SeqID  
        select  @meanSimilarity = AVG(Similarity)
        from    #tmpAllSeqs


        select  top 1 @lastSeqID = SeqID 
        from    #tmpAllSeqs
        order by    abs(Similarity - @meanSimilarity) asc

        Insert into #Subset values (@lastSeqID)

        --- Update #AllSeqs (all candidate SeqIDs)
        truncate table #AllSeqs

        Insert  into #AllSeqs
        select  SeqID
        from    #tmpAllSeqs

        --- Increment size of #Subset
        select @subsetActualSize = count(*) from #Subset

    end

    select SeqID from #Subset

    drop table #Subset
    drop table #AllSeqs
    drop table #tmpAllSeqs

Go
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Job having issues with transaction log...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039391/sql-job-having-issues-with-transaction-log)

Comment: This is useful. I followed your link and find that if I remove those "begin try ... end try...begin catch...end catch", then it works.

Comment: more...(re: checking for XACT_STATE and writes to the log) http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/try_catch.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You are doing the following statements at the end of your stored procedure:

```
select SeqID from #Subset

drop table #Subset
```

Try changing that to

```
Insert Into #resultSeqIDs select SeqID from #Subset
drop table #Subset
```

Then remove the `INSERT` command from where you execute the statement.

Since your #resultSeqIDs Temp table will still be in scope, it will hold all the values you need.

If you are on SQL Server 2008 and above, you can return a table variables - a much better alternative to #temp tables.

Answer (score 0):

If the procedure runs okay, but inserting a record into a temporary table does not, then I'd check the roles of the user running the record insertion. The error message states read-only access.